# Python script not working when run via a CRON job

Tags: python-3.x, linux, unix, cron, raspberry-pi

I am fairly new to python so please bear with me.

I have a certain script in python which performs the following steps:

1. Calls another python script to generate a file (called logfile.txt which contains a lot of text around 25kb which might take upto a couple of mins).
2. after this file generation is complete, it parses the file and looks for a certain text (assume 'power=XXX'), and saves the xxx in a variable.
3. performs a db call and saves this value xxx in a mysql table.

All of this is working fine when the script is executed standalone like this:

```
sudo python3 Parser.py
```

Now I have to do the same in every 15 mins.
So I made an entry in the crontab `sudo crontab -e`

```
*/2 * * * * sudo python3 /home/pi/Parser.py >> /home/pi/cronlogs.txt
```

now this cron job is running fine and generating the cronlogs, where I can see the logs from the python script, but the logfile is not generated, and therefore the parsing is failing(giving 0 as expected when the file is not found)

Things I have tried:

1. I thought it could be a user issue so I printed the user in the logs in teh start of the script and both scenarios the user is root (as expected)
2. Added a file availability check  before calling the parsing code:

   print("file found:",os.path.isfile(fileName))

This resulted in a true!! (even when I can see there is no file in the location)
When i printed the first line of the file it printed empty.

Please help.

OS: Rasbian (Rapberry pi)

Update [Added code snippet which creates the file]:

```
libDir="/home/pi/SIDLMSIntegration/Gurux.DLMS.Library.python/"
    dlmsCmd = " sudo python3 " + libDir + "main.py "
    dlmsCmd += " -S /dev/ttyUSB0:9600:8None1 -c 32 -s 3 -a Low -P ABCD0001 -sn 1 -v 0.0.40.0.0.255 -t Verbose > /home/pi/SIDLMSIntegration/logFile.txt "
    print("dlmsCommand is:",dlmsCmd)
    try:
        os.system(dlmsCmd)
        signedPow=0.0
        activeEnergy=0
        print("Exception did not occur")
    except Exception as err:
        print("Exception Occured:",err)
        pass
    parseFile("Unit.ACTIVE_POWER")
```

Comment: Why are you using sudo in root's crontab?

Comment: I tried without that, but the result is same. It doesnt really matter actually.